# Check if sidebar is rendered?

Tags: sidebar, conditional-content

I want to check if there are sidebars rendered on the front end and if so output some body classes so I can style the page differently. I tried using *is_active_sidebar* but that just returns true if the sidebar contains some widget (is active) - I want to check if it exists on the page. How can I do this?

My code looks like this:

In my single.php

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

In my sidebar.php

```
if ( ! is_active_sidebar() ) {
    // Add something here perhaps?
    return;
}
?>

<div class="sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your certain sidebar widget area is page-specific then I think you need to load classes only to those pages. If so, use `is_page()` with it:

```
if( is_page('that-page') && is_active_sidebar('your-sidebar') ) {
     $class = 'your-class ';
}
```

If it's true for all the inner pages other than the front-page, use:

```
if( !is_front_page() && is_active_sidebar('your-sidebar') ) {
     $class = 'your-class ';
}
```

I think this *is* the PHP way.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'm not thinking correctly about this but I would like some more input. I'm thinking my approach, which would also be PHP, would be more flexible and scalable than checking each page like you suggest.

I would like to somehow reference some function (in functions.php most likely) when is_active_sidebar returns false, like in my example, and then add the body classes. But I think when this renders, all functions have already been fired no?

Comment: If there is a widget assigned `is_active_sidebar` will always return `true`. So using this to add `body_class()` won't make your thing - even with [filter like this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters). You have to go with page-specificity by any means.

Answer (score 1):

I do think that the correct way of doing this would be purely with the WordPress api (in php) which would place all body classes before content is ever sent to the browser.

However, here is a different approach which uses a snippet of javascript and checks that `get_sidebar` is actually called.

```
add_action( 'get_sidebar', 'my_get_sidebar' );
function my_get_sidebar() {
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'your-sidebar' ) ) {
        ?><script>document.body.className += ' with-sidebar';</script><?php
    }
}
```